# Unity can’t put the asset video files with the correct access rights to the mobile project

Tags: ios, video, unity-game-engine

I have some problem with the playing movie on mobile devices. I put .mp4 to the StreamingAsset folder and call the method Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie ("movie.mp4", ...) to play movie.

After building the project on iOS I get the error:

```
[prepareAsset]Error: The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

I check the path where the .mp4 should be

`/var/containers/Bundle/Application/APP_ID/ProductName.app/Data/Raw/movie.mp4` but can't find the Raw folder

[image]
[image]
Does it Unity native bug or maybe some wrong configurations from my side?
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't mind, post picture a of the StreamingAsset folder in the Editor.

Comment: check xcode -> build phases -> copy bundle resources

Comment: @Programmer yes sure please review the link http://screencast.com/t/PJNDYOoLv. I created a small test project to eliminate other errors, but anyway still get them.

Comment: @dopcn please see here http://screencast.com/t/OxcHJuAWNSp I see Data folder but it does not work.